# How to get font width and height in pt or inc.?

Tags: vb.net, graphics, reporting-services, fonts, font-size

How can I calculate width and height for symbol of specific font family.
For example I have Courier New (size 12pt). Can I calculate width and height in points or in inches for each symbol of this font? Which formula I should use?

Comment: What platform? What situation? Are you printing on paper or displaying on screen? Your question is too vague, please add some detail.

Comment: I need to print paper report (8.5in x 11in). I have information about text box width in inches and font size in this text box and need to calculate symbols count in line for Courier New font for different font sizes.

Comment: You can use `CoreText` to access font metrics as [described here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Operations/Operations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH4-SW20).

Comment: I don't use IOS. It's .Net platform (SSRS 2008). I know font size in point units and need to get symbol size in inches or points. I need some formula for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out. For such things we can use .net method MeasureText of the static class TextRenderer

```
String text1 = "Measure this text";
Font arialBold = new Font("Arial", 12.0F);
Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text1, arialBold);
```